# Print all possible subsets of an array

Tags: java, homework

I solved the problem to print all possible subsets of an array. I just want to know a better approach or anything different I could have done.

**Question:** Print all possible subsets of an array.

**My approach:** I know that there are \$2^N\$ (no. of elements in the set) subsets and each subset can be represented with the help of \$N\$-bit binary number. As a part of an assignment I have already made a decimal to binary and to reverse(prints no. in reverse digit by digit) a number program.So I combined the two to solve this question.

**Input:** `{1, 2, 3}`

**Output:** `3, 2, 32, 1, 31, 21, 321`

**My Code:**

```
private static void subset(int[] arr) {
    int size = arr.length;
    int binaryLimit = (int) Math.pow(2, size) - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i <= binaryLimit; i++) {       //generate decimal no.
        //generate corresponding binary no & counter(how many bit binary no. is)
        int N = i;
        int counter = 0;
        int power = 0, binary = 0;
        while (N != 0) {
            int rem = N % 2;
            rem = rem * ((int) Math.pow(10, power));
            binary = binary + rem;
            N = N / 2;
            power++;
            counter++;
        }
        // loop to traverse array
        for (int j = arr.length - 1; j >= arr.length - counter; j--) {
            // if binary no is greater then one digit, compare each digit separately.
            if (counter > 1) {
                int k = binary;
                while (k != 0) {
                    int rem = k % 10;
                    if (rem == 1) {     //if binary digit == 1, print corresponding no. from array
                        System.out.print(arr[j]);
                    }
                    j--;
                    k = k / 10;
                }
                System.out.println();
            } else {
                if (binary == 1) {
                    System.out.println(arr[j]);
                    j--;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Simplify

This could be written a lot simpler.
For each number until `binaryLimit`,
you could iterate over the bits using bit shifting,
and moving the current index in the array,
printing values when the bit is set.

```
private static void printAllSubsets(int... arr) {
    int size = arr.length;
    int binaryLimit = (1 << size) - 1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= binaryLimit; i++) {
        int index = size - 1;
        int num = i;
        while (num > 0) {
            if ((num & 1) == 1) {
                System.out.print(arr[index]);
            }
            index--;
            num >>= 1;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

#### Calculating powers of 2

Note that `Math.pow` takes and returns `double`. Converting between types is ugly, and what's worse, floating point math is fraught with problems in general. Fortunately, for calculating powers of 2, a clean and blazingly fast alternative is to use bit shifting, as demonstrated in the code above.

#### Naming

`subset` is a poor name for a `void` method that prints subsets of elements of an array.

#### Usability

As there is no punctuation between elements as they are printed,
this method will not be very useful for larger arrays,
or arrays where values have more than one digit.

#### Java conventions

Capitalized variable names are normally used for constants,
never for local variables.

#### Method decomposition

Your implementation is very long,
and could have been split to smaller pieces that are easier to read and test individually.

Comment: thanks for your valuable answer. The reason why I don't upvote is that you suggest *premature optimization* which confuses my a little since you emphase readability with you next two points...

Comment: Which part is premature optimization in your opinion?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll surely keep in mind all the pointers. I just want to know what do u mean by the last point

Comment: Does it mean dividing code  further into  smaller methods?

Comment: @ShivamRathi yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: @janos *"Which part is premature optimization in your opinion?"* Its where you suggest not to use the almost self explantory call to the Utillity class `Math.pow()` with the cryptic bit shifting with the point of beeing more performant. There could be a case where you should do it but only after you have *proven by mesurement* that the *more readable* syntax is really drastic dragging down your performance and that the less readable version really solves this problem.

Comment: Thanks @TimothyTruckle. Readability is subjective. I don't see the bit shifting suggestion cryptic at all. Note that `Math.pow` takes and returns `double`. Considering that floating point math is fraught with problems, I think it's important to point out the clean, blazingly fast alternative. Finally, I think the awareness of bit shifting properties is an important skill to cultivate in young programmers, and this example seems a prime opportunity to do that.

Comment: @janos *"`Math.pow` takes and returns `double`. Considering that floating point math is fraught with problems, ..."* This is an argument I can follow and I'd upvote if you change your answer to this statement and relativate the performance part.

Comment: Thanks @TimothyTruckle, not for your precious upvote, but because it's a good point, I updated my answer ;-)

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Apparently readability is in the eye of the beholder.  It hurts me so much to see `Math.pow(2, n)`.  Even more painful was the conversion to a base 10 value named `binary`, only to have the next loop convert "binary" back to base 2.